# I want to updatecomplex XML file attribute value on specific position

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to update my XML on specific position. Please help. Today is my last date of project submission.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A>
  <B>
    <C>
      <D>
        Item1
      </D>
      <E>
        <F type="id" text="Item type">
          <E>
          <G type="id" width="" text="Pen">
            <image name="Pen1" url="www.mysite.com"></image>
          </G>
          </E>
          <E>
            <G type="id" width="" text="Pencil">
              <image name="Pen1" url="www.mysite2.com"></image>
            </G>
          </E>


        </F>
      </E>
      <D>
        Item2
      </D>
      <E>
        <F type="id" text="Item type">
          <E>
            <G type="id" width="" text="Book">
              <image name="Pen1" url="www.mysite3.com"></image>
            </G>
          </E>
          <E>
            <G type="id" width="" text="Book2">
              <image name="Pen1" url="www.mysite4.com"></image>
            </G>
          </E>


        </F>
      </E>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

previously i know the D element vaue, F,G attribute Text value and need to update image URL.
Kindly help, I can't search exact url.
I used

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlPath);

XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("F");
XmlNodeList subelemlist = doc.GetElementsByTagName("G");
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
                        {
                            string attrVal = elemList[i].Attributes["text"].Value;
                            if (attrVal == "Pen")
                            {

                                for (int j = i - 1; j < subelemlist.Count; j++)
                                {
                                    string attrval2 = subelemlist[j].Attributes["URL"].Value;
                                    subelemlist[j].Attributes["URL"].Value = colURL;
                                    doc.Save(xmlPath);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                        }
```

Comment: Last day and you haven't written any code at all? Look up XLinq, and the XDocument object. Then it will be easy. No one here will just write your solution for you.

Comment: And your question is unclear.What is your criteria? Which `URL` you want to change?

Comment: Hi David thanks but I have tried XML text reader, and XDocument with XmlNodeList but I faild. I have no lnowledge of XPath.

Comment: I want to change Image element URL

Comment: @user3151262 if you  failed you should provide your attempt,the code that doesn't work.And then we can help you about finding your mistake.

Comment: @Selman22 I have posted my code kindly suggest.. Or tell me if any new procedure... Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, you are looking for an element that has a `text` property with `Pen` value.And you want to change `image` element's `URL`.If so, you can do the following with `LINQ to XML:`

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var elements = xDoc.Descendants()
                   .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("text") == "Pen");
                   .ToList();

foreach(var item in elements)
{
   var imageElement = item.Elements("image").FirstOrDefault();
   if(imageElement != null)
   {
       imageElement.Attribute("url").Value = newUrl; // change the url value
       xDoc.Save(xmlPath);
   }
}
```

Comment: Saving multiple times seems like a waste though.

Comment: my element name start with ns1 for example ns1:image. so its generating error.The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

Comment: @user3151262 but I don't see any namespace prefix in your xml

Comment: sorry i have not updated but all element has prefix ns1:

Comment: @user3151262 take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387069.aspx , you just need to define an `XNamespace` then use it like `item.Elements(ns + "image")`